# How to test a function which has calls a another API function in it - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocha.js, chai

I have a function, which has another function in it. And in the second function we are making an API call. So how can I write a unit test for this scenario? I don't want to make an actual API call, I want to mock it.

```
 const getData = async (data) => {
    const res = await got.post(url,{
        json: {data}
    });
 
    const data = res.data;
    return data;
 }

function firstFunction(args) {
    // perform some operation with args and it's stored in variable output.
    let output = args;

    let oo = getData(args);
console.log(oo)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When running unit test you **don't** have to call real API calls. You have to encapsulate your component and provide any external information.

With jest you can **mock** the http call and return what you want. And also you can check if the mock has been called.

```
import { got } from "anyplace/got";
import { firstFunction } from "anyplace2";

jest.mock("anyplace/got", () => ({
 // here you provide a mock to any file that imports got to make http calls
 got: {
   // "mockResolvedValue" tells jest to return a promise resolved 
   // with the value provided inside. In this case {data: 'what you 
   // want here'}
   post: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({data: 'what you want here'});
 }
}));

describe('My test', () => {
 beforeEach(() => {
  // This will clear all calls to your mocks. So for every test you will 
  // have your mocks reset to zero calls
  jest.clearAllMocks();
 });

 it('Should call the API call successfully', () => {
  // execute the real method
  firstFunction({arg: 1});

  // check that the API has been called 1 time
  expect(got.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(got.post).toHaveBeenCalledwith("myurlhere", {data: {arg: 1}});
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate it with setTimeout, I further provided a mock response so after 1000ms it will send a Promise with this user array

```
const getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve({
            users: [
                { name: "Michael" },
                { name: "Sarah" },
                { name: "Bill" },
            ]
        }), 1000)
    })
}
```